# Which NBA players have won a high school, NCAA and NBA title?

Tags: basketball, nba, collegiate, amateur

I am trying to figure out which NBA players have won a high school title (any kind), NCAA title and NBA title. I think there are 9 or 10; I know the list includes Magic Johnson and Jerry Lucas, but I don't know who the other ones are.

Comment: As the user who originally posted the accepted answer to this question has left the site, I've taken the liberty of converting the answer to a community wiki. Please edit (or propose an edit to) that answer rather than adding an additional answer if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> NBA Players that won a High School, NCAA and NBA Title

Note: HS titles are state titles unless otherwise noted.

- [Tom Gola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Gola) - HS (Philadelphia Catholic League), NCAA: 1954, NBA: 1956
- [Bill Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Russell) - HS (2x), NCAA: 1955, 1956, NBA: 1957, 1959-1966, 1968, 1969
- [Jerry Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Lucas) - HS: 1956, 1957, NCAA: 1960, NBA: 1973
- [Gail Goodrich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gail_Goodrich) - HS: 1961 (city), NCAA: 1964-1965, NBA: 1972
- [Lucius Allen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_Allen) - HS: [1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wyandotte_High_School#State_championships), NCAA 1967, 1968, NBA: 1971
- [Kareem Abdul-Jabbar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kareem_Abdul-Jabbar) - HS: 1964 (city in 1963, 1965), NCAA: 1967-1969, NBA: 1971, 1980, 1982, 1985, 1987, 1988
- [Bill Walton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Walton) - HS: 1969, 1970, NCAA: 1972, 1973, NBA: 1977, 1986
- [Quinn Buckner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinn_Buckner) - HS: 1971, 1972, NCAA: 1976, NBA: 1984
- [Earvin "Magic" Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Johnson) - HS: [1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everett_High_School_(Michigan)), NCAA: 1979, NBA: 1980, 1982, 1985, 1987, 1988
- [Glen Rice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_Rice) - HS: (unconfirmed), NCAA: 1989, NBA: 2000
- [Jason Terry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Terry) HS: 1994, 1995, NCAA: 1997, NBA: 2011
- [Shane Battier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shane_Battier) - HS (Class B): 1995, 1996, 1997, NCAA: 2001, NBA: 2012, 2013
- [Mario Chalmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Chalmers) - HS: 2002, 2003, NCAA: 2008, NBA: 2012, 2013
- [Sasha Kaun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasha_Kaun) - HS: 2003, NCAA: 2008, NBA: 2016
- [Rick Robey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Robey) - HS: (Brother Martin) 1974, NCAA: (Kentucky) 1978, NBA: (Boston Celtics) 1981

This [12 year old source](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Basketball-Trivia-general-2551/NCAA-Gold-Medal-NBA.htm) gave me a head start.

Comment: Great list. Came here looking for info due to Mario Chalmers winning the Italian league the other day. I wonder if anyone else has done all three AND an overseas title.. Looks like Kaun won in Russia.